# Do you really need a serviceworker to use manifest.json

Tags: web, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I discovered that using `manifest.json` you can specify different icons for your site

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any"><!-- 32×32 -->
<link rel="icon" href="/icon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"><!-- 180×180 -->
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

// manifest.json
{
  "icons": [
    { "src": "/icon-192.png", "type": "image/png", "sizes": "192x192" },
    { "src": "/icon-512.png", "type": "image/png", "sizes": "512x512" }
  ]
}
```

The question is, will this technique works without adding a serviceworker to website?

It seems that service worker caches the website, etc and seems it does something that I do not want to do right now. So can you avoid adding service worker in order icons defined in `manifest.json` to work?

Comment: If adding Icon is the scope then I would prefer doing it via meta tags. But, still you can use manifest json file without service worker. read more about manifest file here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json